# Django Inlineformset with editable Foreign Key Relation

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm trying to create a formset of related objects, where the relation itself is also an editable field.

Let's say we have a models.py like the one below.

```
from django.db import models

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45)

class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
```

Is there a good, pythonic way to create a formset of all Books by a certain Author, and be able to change the Author of any of those books? This would be a particularly useful way to fix any errors in the foreign key relations.

My first instinct was that inlineformset would solve this for me, but I can't seem to get the Author of each book to be an editable field, even when I use custom forms.

Comment: you tried using modelformset_factory?

Comment: That did the trick. I'm still wondering if it's possible with inlineformset_factory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using modelformset_factory will do the trick.  (pulled from my comments here for completeness of the systems question/answer model)